# log4jdbc force return ConnectionSpy driver

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, derby, log4jdbc

For some reason when I use:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:log4jdbc:derby:/home/user/mydb");
```

I tend to get differing connections back. In this case, it's a mixture between:

1. `connection = (org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection) org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@2001280736 (XID = 598), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = /home/user/mydb), (DRDAID = null)`  - Which I don't want

and:

2. `connection = (net.sf.log4jdbc.ConnectionSpy)
   net.sf.log4jdbc.ConnectionSpy@32b260fa` - Which I do want

To be more specific, when I run using a `public static void main` method then it works and I get back `#2` but when I run the same code after running the web application's startup cycle then I get `#1`.

Is there a way to force `log4jdbc` to always return `net.sf.log4jdbc.ConnectionSpy`?

Comment: Perhaps you have a different CLASSPATH in the different cases? Perhaps you are running with a different JDK in the different cases? Perhaps in one case you have registered a different set of JDBC drivers with DriverManager than in the other case?

Comment: Nope, same project, same code, same method even. Only difference is one where I run file the other where I run project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can force wrap the connection in this way:

```
Connection temp = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:log4jdbc:derby:/home/user/mydb");
connection = new net.sf.log4jdbc.ConnectionSpy(temp);
```